# Convert color name to pdfliteral code

Tags: color, luatex, lua

How can I convert a color name (such as used with the `xcolor` package) to a pdfliteral code, like `q 1 0 0 rg` (for red)?

Comment: What is the context here? The drivers for the `color` package normally deal with this for LaTeX users, as this keeps code driver-independent. Also, with a sufficiently up-to-date pdfTeX or LuaTeX, why use `\pdfliteral` rather than `\pdfcolorstack`?

Comment: @JosephWright The context is in Lua code, and I can't use `\color` there because I'm inserting PDF annotations from the Lua code.

Comment: The way that named colours are done is by defining what they convert to: a colour model and then some values. I'd imagine a Lua solution would be done the same way. Can't you just access the appropriate macro definitions from the Lua end?

Comment: @JosephWright Sure, then I guess my question would be if there is such a macro which converts a color name into a space separated triplet of RGB components?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0 % to make everything visible in the pdf 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\usecolor#1{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname\space}

\begin{document}
foo
\pdfliteral{\usecolor{red}}
bar
\end{document}
```

in pdf it is: `1 0 0 rg 1 0 0 RG`

Comment: So `\usecolor{red}` outputs `1 0 0 rg 1 0 0 RG`?

Comment: yes, can already been seen in the pdf

Comment: How to understand the arguments of `\pdfliteral`? I use `{241 240 240 rg}` for green but it shows black

Comment: use values between 0 and 1