# Outline text using TrueType fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, text-decorations, truetype

I'd like to write outlined text. Here is a minimal example, what I'd like to achieve.

[image: Outline text]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{minimal}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{10pt}

\newcommand{\outline}[1]{%
    \textpdfrender{%
        TextRenderingMode=Stroke,%
        FillColor=gray,%
        LineWidth=0.1pt,%
    }{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\fontsize{500}{500}\selectfont%
\outline{a}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

The only problem is, that I need to use TrueType fonts. So that means that I have to use `fontspec` and `xelatex`, but the `pdfrender` package – which I used in this example – does not support `xelatex`.

Can anyone help me, how to make outlined text using TrueType fonts? (Something like in the example.)

Comment: Do you need only few words? Only for some title? I suggest you to use inkscape to write it and export as pdf or ps.

Comment: A duplicate maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25221/outlined-characters

Comment: @Sigur I need a longer text.

Comment: @percusse I've tried that, and it doesn't work with `xelatex`.

Comment: You can use ttf fonts with pdftex provided you use virtual fonts. I prefer this to converting the font, even when the licence would allow it. fontinst can be used to generate most of the files you need more-or-less automatically.

Comment: Another thought: have you considered using a font which is available in outline already? That is, some fonts just are outlines or include outline fonts in their family.

Comment: @cfr I'll try the method you recommended in your previous comment, but at the moment I don't have time for it, perhaps at the end of the month.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a pdflatex (as well as XeLaTeX) approach.  I create a macro `\shadowfy` that can span paragraphs, but can't handle macros in its arguments.   The approach may not be efficient, but it is simple.  It parses the argument, eventually letter by letter, and then stacks a bunch (N, S, E, W, NE, SE, SW, NW) of +/-kerned and raised/lowered `\secondarycolor` copies of the letter, finally laying an unkerned, unraised `\primarycolor` copy of the letter atop it.  With the use of `\def\useanchorwidth{T}` in the `\shadow` definition, it will preserve the letter width of the original letters.  If you comment that line out, the letter spacing will increase to account for the horizontal offset.

The user may set these parameters:

```
\setlength\shadowHoffset{.16pt}
\setlength\shadowVoffset{.08pt}
\def\primarycolor{white}
\def\secondarycolor{black}
```

Here is the MWE.  Because of a "quirk" that I could fix with added code, the value of `\shadowHoffset` should be set to double the value of `\shadowVoffset` if a uniform horizontal/vertical shadow effect is desired.  As you can see, the thickness of the shadow line can be controlled, as well as the colors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}

\newcommand\shadowfy[1]{\expandafter\shadowfypars#1\par\relax\relax}
\long\def\shadowfypars#1\par#2\relax{%
  \ifx#1\relax\else
    \shadowfywords#1 \relax\relax%
  \fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\par\shadowfypars#2\relax\fi%
}
\def\shadowfywords#1 #2\relax{%
  \ifx#1\relax\else
    \shadowfyletters#1\relax\relax%
  \fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \shadowfywords#2\relax\fi%
}
\def\shadowfyletters#1#2\relax{%
  \shadow{#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\shadowfyletters#2\relax\fi}

\newlength\shadowHoffset
\newlength\shadowVoffset
\setlength\shadowHoffset{.2pt}
\setlength\shadowVoffset{.1pt}
\def\primarycolor{white}
\def\secondarycolor{black}

\def\shadow#1{\setstackgap{L}{0pt}\def\stacktype{L}%
\def\useanchorwidth{T}% CAN BE COMMENTEDD FOR MORE INTERLETTER SPACE.
\Longstack{%
\raisebox{0pt}{\textcolor{\primarycolor}{#1}} 
\kern.7\shadowHoffset\raisebox{.7\shadowVoffset}{\textcolor{\secondarycolor}{#1}}
\kern-.7\shadowHoffset\raisebox{.7\shadowVoffset}{\textcolor{\secondarycolor}{#1}}
\kern\shadowHoffset\raisebox{0pt}{\textcolor{\secondarycolor}{#1}}
\kern-\shadowHoffset\raisebox{0pt}{\textcolor{\secondarycolor}{#1}}
\kern.7\shadowHoffset\raisebox{-.7\shadowVoffset}{\textcolor{\secondarycolor}{#1}}
\kern-.7\shadowHoffset\raisebox{-.7\shadowVoffset}{\textcolor{\secondarycolor}{#1}}
\kern0pt\raisebox{\shadowVoffset}{\textcolor{\secondarycolor}{#1}}
\kern0pt\raisebox{-\shadowVoffset}{\textcolor{\secondarycolor}{#1}}%
}}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\mytext{%
This is some sample shadow text.

Multiple paragraphs.
}%
\shadowfy{\mytext}

\setlength\shadowHoffset{.4pt}
\setlength\shadowVoffset{.2pt}
\def\primarycolor{yellow!70}
\def\secondarycolor{blue!80!black}
\shadowfy{\mytext}


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like you just wrote a new plain tex and latex package -- the `fontoutline` package. Just wonderful.

Answer (score 7):

I know the OP wants Xelatex solutions, and here I give a pdf solution, so i don't expect any votes, but wanted to show it anyhow, because it is so less grainy than the other answer of mine.

For this different answer, I steal from our most excellent LaTeX colleague Malipivo, extracting bits of `\pdfliteral` code from his answer at [TikZ: halo around text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18472/tikz-halo-around-text/169549#169549) that end up in my macro `\outline`.  I then basically substitute this `\outline` macro for the `\shadow` macro in my prior answer.  The surrounding `\shadowfy` construct allows line breaking to work (albeit without hyphenation).

EDITED to incorporate Herbert's answer to this question (the `\usecolor` macro), [Convert color name to pdfliteral code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28884/convert-color-name-to-pdfliteral-code), so that colors can be specified in the LaTeX way, rather than as RGB triplets.  This also has the advantage than CMYK colors are now not a problem.

Border and fill colors are defined with `\bordercolor{}` and `\fillcolor{}`, respectively.  Thickness of border defined with `\def\thickness{<decimal>}`, though I don't know the units of the decimal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\input pdf-trans
\newbox\qbox
\def\usecolor#1{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname\space}
\newcommand\bordercolor[1]{\colsplit{1}{#1}}
\newcommand\fillcolor[1]{\colsplit{0}{#1}}
\newcommand\outline[1]{\leavevmode%
  \def\maltext{#1}%
  \setbox\qbox=\hbox{\maltext}%
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr \thickness\space w \fillcol\space \bordercol\space}{}%
  \copy\qbox%
}
\newcommand\shadowfy[1]{\expandafter\shadowfypars#1\par\relax\relax}
\long\def\shadowfypars#1\par#2\relax{%
  \ifx#1\relax\else
    \shadowfywords#1 \relax\relax%
  \fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\par\shadowfypars#2\relax\fi%
}
\def\shadowfywords#1 #2\relax{%
  \outline{#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \shadowfywords#2\relax\fi%
}
\newcommand\colsplit[2]{\colorlet{tmpcolor}{#2}\edef\tmp{\usecolor{tmpcolor}}%
  \def\tmpB{}\expandafter\colsplithelp\tmp\relax%
  \ifnum0=#1\relax\edef\fillcol{\tmpB}\else\edef\bordercol{\tmpC}\fi}
\def\colsplithelp#1#2 #3\relax{%
  \edef\tmpB{\tmpB#1#2 }%
  \ifnum `#1>`9\relax\def\tmpC{#3}\else\colsplithelp#3\relax\fi
}
\begin{document}
\bordercolor{black}
\fillcolor{white}
\def\thickness{.1}
\newcommand\mytext{This is some sample shadow text.\par Multiple paragraphs.}%
\shadowfy{\mytext}

\def\thickness{0.15}
\bordercolor{blue!70!black}
\fillcolor{yellow}
\shadowfy{\mytext}

\bordercolor{black}
\fillcolor{white}
\def\thickness{.02}{\Huge\shadowfy{a}}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Here is a `\Huge` letter "a", with the settings

```
\bordercolor{black}
\fillcolor{white}
\def\thickness{.02}
```

[image]