# Particular headings to create using LaTeX

Tags: sectioning, framed, shadows

I would like to create the following heading using LaTeX:

[image]

May anyone please advise on the code to do so? In particular, I would like to capture

1. The color
2. The border
3. The shadow

Thank you!

Comment: For the color/border question, maybe this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125578/outline-text-using-truetype-fonts, but it does not address shadow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the command to a chapter heading for demonstration. The code that formats the text is the `tikzpicture` environment. It can be moved elsewhere easily.

The place to change the text and the color are indicated in the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{1.2pt}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{1pt}
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      %                V---------------------------V <- Text goes here
      \def\textoftitle{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
      \node at ( 0.04,-0.04) {\contour{black!25!white}{\color{white}\Huge \textoftitle}};
      \node at ( 0.03,-0.03) {\contour{black!50!white}{\color{white}\Huge \textoftitle}};
      \node at ( 0.02,-0.02) {\contour{black!75!white}{\color{white}\Huge \textoftitle}};
      \node at ( 0.01,-0.01) {\contour{black}{\color{white}\Huge \textoftitle}};
      %                                       VV Amount of yellow mixed with black (70% yellow + 30% black)
      \node at ( 0.00, 0.00) {\contour{yellow!70!black}{\color{white}\Huge \textoftitle}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }%

\begin{document}
 \chapter{Chap}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic. This is great; thank you. A couple of questions: (1) How do I change the text?; (2) How may I alternate the level of color; i.e a darker yellow. Cheers mate.

Comment: @GustavoLouisG.Montańo I updated my post to answer your questions.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you @Phelype Oleinik for your time and help.