# How can I make math symbols one color and have a different color outline?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols, color, contour

When I use something like `\[\textcolor{White}{\contour{green}{\alpha}}\]` the alpha comes out in green, not white, and has no outline whatsoever. How can I fix this? I want it to be in white with a green outline.

Thanks for your help.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[runin]{abstract}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{geometry} %Geometry package to change the text width
\geometry{textwidth=8cm} %8cm Text width
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
 \[\textcolor{White}{\contour{green}{\alpha}}\]
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**

I just realized that actually it does work-although only partially. I was just zoomed out so I didn't notice the difference in color. HOWEVER, it doesn't let the maths be written like it usually is with `\[...\]`; it only outputs the maths the size of `\(...\)` even when I explicitly use `\[...\]`.

Comment: As far as I know, it can only be  done with `pstricks` – more precisely, the `\pscharpath`  command from `pst-text`  has this possibility.

Comment: @Bernard please could you elaborate a bit? I'm not a very advacned LaTeX user. I'll add `\usepackage{pstricks}`, then what?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've just tested, and there seems to be problems with mathmode, which is new to me. It used to work a few years ago. I don't have time  at the moment, but I'll take a look this evening.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks so much!

Comment: Personally, I don't think so, as there aren't so many questions on this topic, as far as I know, and your code might be helpful.

Comment: @Bernard ok, thanks. However, there's another problem that I just realized; please see my edit. Sorry to keep bothering you.

Comment: You don't bother me. For  a letter, the size is the same for in-line and displaystyle formula, so I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @Bernard Eg `\prod` and `\sum` come out small.

Comment: If you want larger \pro and \sum, you add  `\displaystyle` on entering math mode. There's also the `\mathlarger` command from package `relsize`.

Answer (score 5):

Works in pdflatex only.  However, for other possibilities, see [Outline text using TrueType fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125578/outline-text-using-truetype-fonts).  Here, one can control the colors and the outline thickness as settable parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\input pdf-trans
\newbox\qbox
\def\usecolor#1{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname\space}
\newcommand\bordercolor[1]{\colsplit{1}{#1}}
\newcommand\fillcolor[1]{\colsplit{0}{#1}}
\newcommand\outline[1]{\leavevmode%
  \def\maltext{#1}%
  \setbox\qbox=\hbox{\maltext}%
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr \thickness\space w \fillcol\space \bordercol\space}{}%
  \copy\qbox%
}
\newcommand\colsplit[2]{\colorlet{tmpcolor}{#2}\edef\tmp{\usecolor{tmpcolor}}%
  \def\tmpB{}\expandafter\colsplithelp\tmp\relax%
  \ifnum0=#1\relax\edef\fillcol{\tmpB}\else\edef\bordercol{\tmpC}\fi}
\def\colsplithelp#1#2 #3\relax{%
  \edef\tmpB{\tmpB#1#2 }%
  \ifnum `#1>`9\relax\def\tmpC{#3}\else\colsplithelp#3\relax\fi
}
\begin{document}
\bordercolor{black}
\fillcolor{white}
\def\thickness{.1}
\outline{$\alpha$}

\def\thickness{0.15}
\bordercolor{blue!70!black}
\fillcolor{yellow}
\outline{$\alpha$}

\bordercolor{green!70!black}
\fillcolor{white}
\def\thickness{.2}

$x\outline{$\alpha$}y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change graphic state at PDF primitive level. PDF includes commands for filling characters or stroking or both. The `0 Tr` means only filling (it is default) and `2 Tr` means filling plus stroking. The line width of stroking is given by `num w`. The colors can be set independently for filling (`rg` for RGB or `k` for CMYK) and for stroking (`RG` or `K`).

Your task seems like this from PDF primitive point of view:

```
\pdfliteral{1 1 0 rg 1 0 0 RG 2 Tr .2 w}% yellow filing, red stroking
$\alpha + b = c$ % the formula has yellow symbols with red outlines.
\pdfliteral{0 g 0 G 0 Tr 0 w}%
Normal text in black follows.

\bye
```